# How to create sandbox using crictl

Tags: kubernetes

I am following [Run a pod sandbox](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/cri-containerd/blob/master/docs/crictl.md#run-a-pod-sandbox-using-a-config-file) link to create a sandbox using crictl. I am getting below error

```
root@cri-master:~# crictl runs sandbox-config.json
FATA[0000] run pod sandbox failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc =failed to setup network for sandbox     "3ad790c715c817d22e6f6df95bf612dbc0ceaf05d2d94f94e62aa4b57234ea57": pods "nginx-sandbox" not found
```

Please could someone tell me what is being done wrong here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I posted same question in the cri-containerd github issue and I got this answer. This explains everything

[Unable to create sandbox](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/cri-containerd/issues/520)

> IIRC, calico daemonset watch apiserver to get a list of pods, and apply network configuration based on the pod spec. I think this is the problem.
>
> If you use `crictl create` a sandbox yourself, there won't be corresponding pod on apiserver, thus calico reports that error.
>
> In fact, we don't recommend user to run `crictl runs` and `crictl create` on a Kubernetes node , those commands are there just for some special debug case. And that's also why we make the command so hard to use (user need to prepare for a configuration file to create a sandbox/container).
>
> In fact, even if you are able to create the sandbox, `kubelet` will eventually stop and delete it because it doesn't see the corresponding pod on apiserver.
>
> If you just want to try crictl, the error is caused by the reason above.
> If you just want to try create a pod, use kubectl instead. :)